# ImageView fit to full height on landscape screen

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

I have problem with fit square image to height of screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/test_l">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView12"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/kwadrat"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"

        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The image @kwadrat is square size.
How to change the width of border image?
I tried set scaleType="fitXY" and adjustViewBounds="true" but it not give the good result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbr6p.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYgW4.png)

EDIT: 
I downloaded new version of Android Studio and all fit fine.
set scaleType="fitXY", adjustViewBounds="true" and is nice square.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` but the resolution of your picture will not be good when it's stretched like that.

```
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView12"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/kwadrat"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

Comment: Any of the scale type isnt good. fitXY, fitCenter, Crop wont work. When i set android:layout_height="match_parent"  the border of image change to rectangel. I want it square

Comment: Ah, I see the problem with that, I've edited the answer. fitCenter is right, but you need to set the width to `match_parent` too. When the width is set to `wrap_content` then the width of the view is already fixed at the same as the width of the image. The image isn't going to scale up to the size you expect as it has already been told to only be as wide as the original image.

Comment: Yea, but if I set android:layout_width="match_parent" the border of image is on full screen (image is square but the border isnt square). Then I cant set new item ToRight/Left of my Image.

Comment: Ah, if you want to do that too, maybe RelativeLayout won't do what you need. Perhaps PercentRelativeLayout is better for this purpose. It has an aspectRatio property you can use, so you could set the height to be the whole screen then use the aspectRatio to make it square. Some info about this topic: https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/ZQS29a5yroK

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying android:scaleType="centerCrop"? From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html):

> Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding). The image is then centered in the view

Note that, with your specified ImageView's width and height as "wrap_content" and "match_parent" (respectively), if you want the ImageView to appear square, the source image should be square though.